# Backdrop does not show in layout mode, blender 3.2

Tags: video, scene

I have nodes in composite with a movie as background and the active scene. But when I want to work in the scene with the backdrop there is movie. That worked in blender 2.6 without nodes, just  the video as background and working in the scene in the foreground.
The composite should do the same, but I don't get it to work.
I don't see any reference what I can do here, but I am sure it works somehow, but it is hidden somewhere in the menu structure.
Thanks
Siegfried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Until now (Blender 3.3) the compositor in Blender 2.8 or higher does not work in real-time (I don't know version 2.6 unfortunately). The compositor is executed after the render (F12). In the future, there will be a real-time compositor.  If you need a movie in the viewport for reference you can import it as a plane (enable the addon "[Import Images As Plane](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html)) or use the [Camera Background Image](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.3/render/cameras.html#background-images). Look trough the camera to see it